# Help indentify this species of snake/worm

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology

I stumbled upon this snake during my routine walking in the nature park near me. The location is southern India.

[image]

[image]
Time if observation is 6 30 PM.

The length was approximately 1 feet. I could see the tongue coming out just like normal snakes.

The tail was pointed. Guessing it to be red boa.

Comment: I would say not red boa - head shape is wrong as is colouration. I would hazard a guess at Kerela shieldtail based on the pics here: http://indiansnakes.org/

Answer (score 2):

Body shape, coloration (especially lateral yellow stripe) and location all lead me to think this is some species of [*Uropeltis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropeltis) snake, all of which are endemic to India.

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropeltis)  lists 25 species in this genus, and at least [some species](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30313609/) are only differentiated by closely examining the number of scales or size of shields.

One common species is [*Uropeltis eliottii*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropeltis_ellioti), but I'll admit the coloration looks a tad too dark for your specimen.

[image]

<sup>Source: [The Reptile Database](https://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Uropeltis&species=ellioti)</sup>

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uropeltis_ellioti) and [The Reptile Database](https://reptile-database.reptarium.cz/species?genus=Uropeltis&species=ellioti), this species is endemic to southern India.

In 2018, a new species, *Uropeltis bhupathy* was described by [Jins et al (2018)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324951561_A_new_species_of_Uropeltis_Cuvier_1829_Serpentes_Uropeltidae_from_the_Anaikatty_Hills_of_the_Western_Ghats_of_India) from the Anaikatty Hills of the Western Ghats of Tamil Nadu (*is this near you?*), and I think the scale coloration looks closer to your specimen.

[image]

<sup>Source: [Jins et al (2018)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324951561_A_new_species_of_Uropeltis_Cuvier_1829_Serpentes_Uropeltidae_from_the_Anaikatty_Hills_of_the_Western_Ghats_of_India)</sup>

---

<sup>Jins, V.J., Sampaio, F.L. and Gower, D.J., 2018. A new species of Uropeltis Cuvier, 1829 (Serpentes: Uropeltidae) from the Anaikatty Hills of the Western Ghats of India. *Zootaxa*, 4415(3), pp.401-422.</sup>

Comment: The color difference could be caused by the camera and the lighting (e.g. the scales reflecting light). I would guess your answer is right. Some cameras misrepresent colors, too; I have one that makes everything look more blue and less red than it appears. But yeah, we'd probably have to interrogate the questioner considerably to find out (about whether a flash was used, if a light was shining on the snake, if the snake was very reflective, if red things look less red with that camera, etc.)